# Hoover UH72635 Belt Clutch Problem

Tags: vacuum

[image]When I removed my old belt, I noticed the plastic cover on the clutch was worn through.  I believe it needs to be replaced because it will damage the new belt due to the rough surface.  Wondering if its possible to do it myself or whether I have to take it to a repair shop.  Thoughts?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the worn clutch? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: If it's like the vacuums I've fixed in the past, the majority of the effort will be finding the part.  Putting the new one in probably wouldn't be too hard if you know which end of the screwdriver to hold.